# TableOperation.Retrieve generic form vs. non-generic form

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

What is the difference between `TableOperation.Retrieve()` and `TableOperation.Retrieve<T>()` in the Azure API? Both return a `TableOperation` and MSDN isn't very clear on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, MSDN is not clear about this. The difference is when you call the generic version of the method it knows the type of the entity resolver to use. You can this see by looking at the source of the [generic version here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/ClassLibraryCommon/Table/TableOperation.cs) and the [non-generic here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Table/TableOperation.Common.cs).